# How to determine confidence level in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

When a user is responding to a question in DialogFlow, is there a way to obtain the confidence levels that was achieved for a specific phrase? Example:
Q: What is the capital of Germany?
A: Berlin

I would like to read back how well the AI understood the user, e.g.:

He said: "Boerlin" ---> 87.3% confidence level that he said "Berlin"

Is there a way to read back this kind of information?

Comment: welcome to SO!  You might get better responses with a more specifics about how you are interfacing with DialogFlow, ie: what you mean by "read back".  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am programming a dialogue directly in DialogFlow (api.ai). By "read back" I mean the following: When the users says a word, the AI processes it and determines a confidence level (how likely is the word said actually the word "Berlin". Is there a way to get this confidence level from the AI? Best, Thomas

Comment: Hi, Thomas.I am facing the similar issue. Did you find any way ? Please help.

Comment: Hi Mohit, I did not get a response on Stack but talked to someone with quite some experience, Tellez Ng me that currently you cannot read back that value. If you should find a solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas. Have a look at the Google Apis DetectIntent Documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions/detectIntent

Using the method is as follows:

```
POST https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{DialogFlowProjectName}/agent/sessions/{SessionId}:detectIntent
```

The body:

```
{
  "queryInput": {
    "text": {
      "text": "{Question You would like to ask}",
      "languageCode": "en-EN"
    }
  }
}
```

It Uses OAuth2.0 you can use google OAuth Sandbox to generate a temporary token to use
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

In the response there will be a field:

```
"intentDetectionConfidence": 0.6776556,
 "intent": {
            "name": "{IntentId}",
            "displayName": "{IntentName}"
        }
```