# Dialogflow receive confidence scores for all intents

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to get a conifdence score for all intents for a query in Dialogflow? This would be helpful in navigating flow of conversation.

Cheers

Comment: If you mean you want to get the [`intentDetectionConfidence`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/QueryResult) for all intents, not just the one that was matched, then I don't think this is possible. The entire speech recognition engine is pretty much a black box unfortunately.

Comment: Damn, that’s unfortunate

Comment: Hi i answered the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039722/how-to-determine-confidence-level-in-dialogflow/56122074#56122074